# Using Non-Euclidean Distance Matrix in Multi-Dimensional Scaling

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, multidimensional-scaling

I'm trying to use a non-euclidean distance matrix in MDS. Specifically, I'm using cmdscale in R. The resulting eigen vector appears to have huge negative values. From what I've read it appears that cmdscale is ignoring all the negative eigen values.  This appears to result in a very low goodness-of-fit.

Are there any specific R libraries that can handle non-euclidean distance matrices for MDS? Or is there any pre-processing or post-processing that I could to make MDS work better?

If none of the above are possible, Is it safe to assume that MDS is not suited for my data?

Comment: Do you mean with distance matrix the matrix of dissimilarities used as input or the distance matrix that is fitted to the dissimilarities?

Comment: I mean the matrix of dissimilarities used as input.

Comment: The farther the input dissimilarities from being euclidean the greater are the negative eigenvalues. Your dissimilarities are probably even far from being metric. Try to square them or take the root - will the fit be better? Try nonmetric MDS instead of metric one - will that help? Try to request more dimensions. Try another stress (unfit) criterion.